# GOOGLE MAPS EROR

Tags: flutter

I TAKE THİS EROR.
Exception has occurred.
PlatformException (PlatformException(error, API key not found.  Check that  is in the  element of AndroidManifest.xml, null, java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that  is in the  element of AndroidManifest.xml
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.p.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@210214081@21.02.14 (120400-0):6)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.auth.f.i(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@210214081@21.02.14 (120400-0):1)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@210214081@21.02.14 (120400-0):24)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.newMapViewDelegate(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@210214081@21.02.14 (120400-0):2)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.g.aX(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@210214081@21.02.14 (120400-0):18)
at dt.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@210214081@21.02.14 (120400-0):4)
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:914)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zza.zza(Unknown Source:10)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzf.zza(Unknown Source:19)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$zzb.createDelegate(Unknown Source:13)
at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.zaa(Unknown Source:18)
at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.onCreate(Unknown Source:22)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.onCreate(Unknown Source:26)
at io.flutter.plugins.googlemaps.GoogleMapController.onCreate(GoogleMapController.java:544)
at androidx.lifecycle.FullLifecycleObserverAdapter.onStateChanged(FullLifecycleObserverAdapter.java:36)
at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:361)
at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.java:188)
at io.flutter.plugins.googlemaps.GoogleMapController.init(GoogleMapController.java:113)
at io.flutter.plugins.googlemaps.GoogleMapBuilder.build(GoogleMapBuilder.java:38)
at io.flutter.plugins.googlemaps.GoogleMapFactory.create(GoogleMapFactory.java:53)
at io.flutter.plugin.platform.SingleViewPresentation.onCreate(SingleViewPresentation.java:186)
at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:421)
at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:315)
at android.app.Presentation.show(Presentation.java:257)
at io.flutter.plugin.platform.VirtualDisplayController.(VirtualDisplayController.java:95)
at io.flutter.plugin.platform.VirtualDisplayController.create(VirtualDisplayController.java:48)
at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewsController$1.createVirtualDisplayForPlatformView(PlatformViewsController.java:207)
at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.create(PlatformViewsChannel.java:104)
at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.onMethodCall(PlatformViewsChannel.java:59)
at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:818)
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:336)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:174)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7399)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:502)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:980)
))

main code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRsdy.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzDqi.jpg)

pubspec.yaml
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOe5M.jpg)

AndroidManifest.xml
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiZ2m.jpg)

Comment: Please add your error inside block quotes like \`\`\`\`\`\`. And instead of posting images of your code, add the code itself, inside the code blocks that is ``````. Refer to [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have add your `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="YOUR-KEY-HERE"/>` inside the activity tag. It should be under `<application>` tag.

Comment: I still have problem.now program is working but ı only see grey screen

Comment: check your data connection

Comment: thank you. problem is data connection and i fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, but now I am seeing the application gray screen. I can't see the map